# I tried using switch/ iif function in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Hello i tried using both switch as well as iif function in ssrs report. I have a column(Delta) which has values and need to set image depending on column values. Below is my switch statement

```
=Switch(
        Fields!Delta.Value =0,"arrowzero.jpg",
        Fields!Delta.Value >0,"arrowup.jpg",
        Fields!Delta.Value <0,"arrowup.jpg",
        Fields!Delta.Value ="CNC","arrowblack.jpg"
       )
```

Switch statement is working for all cases except last case "CNC".

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations that might help you fix this.

1. You switch statement uses the same column however the first three evaluate it numerically, the last one against a string. Is this correct?
2. Is the image called "arrowblack.jpg", is there a typo here?
3. If the last option is supposed be act like an `ELSE` then you can replace `Fields!Delta.Value ="CNC","arrowblack.jpg"` with `True,"arrowblack.jpg"`

Comment: You switch statement uses the same column however the first three evaluate it numerically, the last one against a string. Is this correct? Yes first 3 are numeric and last one is string

Is the image called "arrowblack.jpg", is there a typo here? Nope

If the last option is supposed be act like an ELSE then you can replace Fields!Delta.Value ="CNC","arrowblack.jpg" with True,"arrowblack.jpg" Yes will try it

Comment: Add a new column and set the value expression to the same `SWITCH` expression. If it is working then you should see the filenames in the new column. Once we know if the filenames are being returned correctly or not we can look at the next step.

Comment: One more thing, what are you getting back for the "CNC" records, is it not showing an image or is it the wrong image?

Comment: It does not show me any image just a red cross sign is display

Comment: And what do you get when you add a new column just displaying the result of the switch as I suggested earlier?

Comment: For all numeric values its working but no image name is displayed for CNC

Comment: I think oyu will need to script a smaple of your data and report layout then I can try to reproduce